# Arduino - Writing int array with for loop doesn't work

Tags: arduino

I am a college student so I'm still learning a lot. I ran into something interesting while making a project. I have this segment of code that works when it isn't placed in a for loop, but doesn't work when it is. I just want to understand why. Here is my code:

```
void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
  int a[8];
  for(int i=0;i<8;i++) {
    a[i]=pow(2,i);
  }

  for(int i=0;i<8;i++) {
    Serial.print(a[i]);
  }
}

void loop() {
}
```

Here is the same code written without the first for loop (where the data gets written into the array):

```
void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
  int a[8];
  a[0]=pow(2,0);
  a[1]=pow(2,1);
  a[2]=pow(2,2);
  a[3]=pow(2,3);
  a[4]=pow(2,4);
  a[5]=pow(2,5);
  a[6]=pow(2,6);
  a[7]=pow(2,7);
  for(int i=0;i<8;i++) {
    Serial.print(a[i]);
  }
}

void loop() {
}
```

The first code outputs:

```
1
2
3
7
15
31
63
127
```

While the second code outputs:

```
1
2
4
8
16
32
64
128
```

Does anybody know? I really want to know why.

Comment: Is that your whole code?

Comment: 1) Don't spam tags of unrelated languages. 2) Read [ask].

Comment: If you are getting into embedded systems prefer `(1 << i)` rather than `pow(2,i)`.  The latter function returns floating point whereas the first can usually be translated into one or two assembly language instructions.

Comment: I was under the impression that arduino idea in both C and C++. Also, sorry. This was my first post I've ever made.

Comment: what happens if you change this line in the loop: `a[i]=pow(2,i);` to `a[i]=(int) pow(2,i);`?  I doubt it would matter.

Comment: And yes, this is my whole code.

Comment: Make the compiler generate assembly code for your two cases.  See how the compiler is translating your source code.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews -- that's probably the explanation for the differnc between the two approaches. The second uses constants, so the call to ’pow` is replac d. Y a shift which is, in turn, optimized out. The first passes a variable to `pow`, so it's harder to optimize.

Comment: 'a[i]=(int) pow(2,i);' Doesn't work either

Comment: @bruceg -- adding that cast just makes explicit the conversion that the code does anyway. I doubt that it will change the result.

Comment: You may get more performance and better accuracy by using an `unsigned int`.  The binary shift left operator is defined for `unsigned int`.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews Thanks, that worked. Still curious as to exactly why

Comment: According to Arduino doc, the pow returns a double, can you change the int type to double and see the result

Comment: @ThomasMatthews `unsigned int` did not work. but `(1<<i)` did

Comment: @chamba `double` also works. still curious as to why int doesn't I'm assuming it has to do with bits?

Comment: I don't understand.  How does `unsigned int number = 1 << i;` not work?

Comment: @ThomasMatthews I meant if I made the variable `unsigned int` by itself did not work. `1<<I` in fact did work.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are experiencing floating point round off. 2^4 will actually give you a value closer to 15.9999 and when this is assigned to an int, it truncates the decimal to 15. I would suggest doing bit shift operations when using powers of 2, such that:

```
  for(int i=0;i<8;i++)
  {
    a[i]=(1 << i);
  }
```

If you want to read up on bit shifting, look [here](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Reference/Bitshift).
If you want to know more about the floating point round off, look [here](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/101163/what-causes-floating-point-rounding-errors).

Additionally if you wanted just a quick fix to your code closer to what you have, I believe this will also work:

```
  for(int i=0;i<8;i++)
  {
    a[i]= (int) round( pow(2, i) );
  }
```

This will round the floating result properly before casting it to an int.

Comment: Thank you! I actually was learning shift registering with the 74HC595 when I found this problem. It makes a lot more sense now

Comment: Can you explain why does 2^4 gives a value closer to 15.9999?

Comment: @appa yip yip I believe it is because the standard math library uses approximation algorithms regardless of the type of parameters, so you will have floating point calculations regardless of if you use ints or not.

Comment: @EastonBornemeier Oh, I see. Thank you for explaining it :)